# Longest Run of Duplicate Values

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops, duplicates

I am trying to find the longest run of similar values in an array, but for some reason my loop doesn't work and it throws an irrelevant number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};
  int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  int count;

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j <= size; j++) {
      if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  cout << count << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

For example: The above code should return 4 because the longest run of a similar value is 4 times as

> (1 * 4)

but printing `count` variable, it shows 9, which is not even the size of the array.

Comment: Your innerloop would get all the 1s and then it would go again with i=1 to size-1, counting some a second, third, fourth etc time.  I don't see any logic for keeping track of how many numbers having duplicate values (and which one is the most).  I also think you may run past the array sequence end end up counting a random number past the array addresses.

Comment: Explain to me **exactly** how your code is supposed to work. What does every single line do?

Comment: well it is supposed to loop through an array two times, then compare each element with its neighbor, and if it matched, then it should add one to the counter. At the end it should just display how many items matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your never resetting count to 0 if the run of duplicates ever ends and you never check if the current run is smaller than the previous run. I've added this into the code below in the form of the `int max` variable that gets the value of count if it is larger than its current value at the end of a run. I've also changed the loop setup as you need to check the number equals itself first to get a run length of 1 and you need to loop until `j < size` not `j <= size`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};
  int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  int count = 0;
  int max = 0;
  int current = arr[0];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if(arr[i] == current) {
        count++;
      } else if(arr[i] != current && (size - i) > 1) { //check not at end of the array 
          if(count > max){
            max = count;
          }
        count = 1;
        current = arr[i];
      }
  }
  if(count > max)
    max = count; //set count to max if larger in case you reached end of the array and run hasn't ended

  cout << max << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @KDH, it works now, I didn't know I have to reset the counter back.

Comment: No worries @Lima. There is another issue I just thought of! I've updated my answer to fix it. If it solves your issue would you mind marking it as the correct answer so people know it's been solved. Cheers

Comment: Thank you @KDH, the issue was solved even with the first snap of code you provided. And yes, I marked it as the correct Answer. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Sweet you're welcome! The second snap of code just makes sure that if you have an array like {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2 } it will set the last run as the biggest as the first version wouldn't.